# Shell Scripting : Good idea, wrote it bad

Tags: shell, scripting

I have to make a shell script that returns a list with all files that have word 'hello' on 3 or more lines.

I know the idea, but I think I wrote my script bad.

```
nr=$(ls | wc -l )

for ((i = 0; i < nr ; i++));do

    fis[$i]=$(ls | sed -n '$i p')

done

for ((i = 0; i < nr ; i++));do

    if [$(cat $(fis[$i]) | grep 'hello' | wc -l) -gt 2 ];

    then

        echo $( fis[$i])

    fi

done
```

First I take a number "nr" that returns number of files, than a for from 0 to nr and put in an array fis[i] all the files, selecting each line with sed. And than, if fis[i] contains 'hello' on at least 3 lines, I display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote too much code I think.

You can use this `for loop`:

```
files=()
for f in *; do
   [[ $(grep -c "hello" "$f") -gt 2 ]] && files+=("$f")
done

printf "List of files with more than 2 occurrences of 'hello' is:\n"
printf "%s\n" "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: I know that your code is good, but I would prefer to know what's wrong with mine.

Comment: Few things like use of ls, wc, 2 for loops, sed, cat isn't really needed. It can be done in a single `for loop` as I showed above.